# OpenApi (swagger) Generate Mixed Types data with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

How I can generate Mixed Types in OpenApi (show down ) with @RequestParam

```
oneOf:
 - type: string
 - type: integer
```